# Why Lazy load routing is not working in angular12?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have modules which i want to lazy load. But when i defining their lazy load routes so these routes are not working and not loading in browser. When i try to navigate to their route by browser so it takes me to dashboard every time.

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ClaimModule } from './modules/claim/claim.module';
import { DependentModule } from './modules/dependent/dependent.module';
import { ProfileModule } from './modules/profile/profile.module';

import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    ClaimModule,
    DependentModule,
    ProfileModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    ModalModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-module.routing.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './core/components/login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './core/guard/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'dependent',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/dependent/dependent.module').then(m => m.DependentModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

profile-module.routing.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProfileComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProfileRoutingModule { }
```

profile.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile.component';
import { ProfileRoutingModule } from './profile-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProfileRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [ProfileComponent]
})
export class ProfileModule { }
```

core-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./../modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CoreRoutingModule { }
```

layout.component.html

```js
<div class="wrapper w-100">

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <app-header></app-header>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <app-control-sidebar></app-control-sidebar>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->

  <!-- Main Footer -->
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->
```

Here is my all `route` configuration. But whenever i try to navigate to `/profile` `route` so it always takes me to dashboard. I don't know why it is not loading the `module` and its `component`.

Comment: You are eagerly importing the modules you want to lazy load in your AppModule. Remove the modules you want to lazy load from your AppModule's import section and be sure to not import them anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app-module.routing.ts

empty path should have pathMatch: 'full' otherwise all url will go to coreRoutingModule

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule),
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

Docs: https://angular.io/api/router/Route#pathMatch